# How do I run debian-installer-launcher on a non-live debian system?

Tags: debian, debian-installer

As per the title. I have a working debian install, and I would like to launch the debian installer from that install, rather than booting from usb.

Initial attempts at running it present me with this:

```
con@unbound ~> sudo debian-installer-launcher
ERROR: 'kexec' is not a valid plugin. Check and try again.
umount: /run/live/installer: no mount point specified.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The question is pretty clear, and I am trying to find a solution myself.